# Hide Clojure REPL from command-tab application switcher via lein, command line, or emacs

Tags: macos, emacs, clojure, leiningen, dock

When starting a clojure app via lein on osx, the java coffee cup icon shows in the dock/app switcher.  How can this be hidden when:

- running from the command line
- running a repl from the command line
- running from emacs via cider

It all revolves around the environmental variable that gets "-Dapple.awt.UIElement=true" to the running process.

Answer (score 3):

From the command line, before running the target program:

```
`export JVM_OPTS="-Dapple.awt.UIElement=true"`
```

Same as above, added to your lein project.clj file:

```
:jvm-opts ["-Dapple.awt.UIElement=true"]
```

From emacs, running a **REPL** via cider.  Add the following to your .emacs file.

```
(setenv "LEIN_JVM_OPTS" "-Dapple.awt.UIElement=true")
```